# Which method of canonical EntityFunctions for .ToString()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am using EF and if I use expression like:

```
JobLinkId = jobItem.joblinkid.ToString()
```

it throws error because it is C# function. Which method of EF canonical functions should I use for this?

Comment: what to you mean by "because it is C#function"? The only function I can identify there is ToString() - is JobLinkId, jobItem or joblinkid a function?

Comment: The error you're getting should be included in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're trying to use `ToString` in `Linq to Entities` query. If so then its impossible to use it there. The only walkaround i know is to use `ToList` on query and then use `Linq to Objects` to get result with `ToString`.

Answer (score -1):

To something like this:

instead of `JobItem.joblinkid.ToString()` use only `JobItem.joblinkid` inside your query and do a select afterwards:

```
myQuery.ToArray().Select(x => x.joblinkid.ToString())
```

I hope you get it.
In any case: int is *better* than string, just wait till you really need the string and convert then.

Comment: JobLinkId  is a string and jobItem.joblinkid is of int type. I want to convert int to string using Canonical function.

Comment: oh sorry - than I don't know where the problem might be. Can you post the exception (ToString is "allways" there, this has nothing to do with EF)

Comment: I get: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."