# SQLite.Net-PCL No such function: ToString

Tags: c#, uwp, sqlite-net, sqlite.net

I have Employees table with `Name`(string) and `Number`(int) columns.

I can search for employees for anything. So,

```
var query = cnn.Table<Employees>()
               .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search) || 
                           x.Number.ToString().Contains(search));
```

> An exception of type 'SQLite.Net.SQLiteException' occurred in SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: no such function: tostring

How can I cast Number column to string?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using the EntityFunctons (more general than SqlFunctons).

Comment: No. But according [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397176/which-method-of-canonical-entityfunctions-for-tostring) is not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that SQLLite linq doesn't know what is `ToString()` - that is a C# method that can be overridden to do anything. You should use [`SqlFunctions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var query = cnn.Table<Employees>()
               .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search) ||              
                           SqlFunctions.StringConvert((int)x.Number).Contains(search));
```

Another solution can be to add a `.ToList()`/`AsEnumerable()` before the `where` but then that filtering will happen in the c# instead of the database

---

One can also:

```
var query = cnn.Table<Employees>()
               .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search) || x.Number > 0)
               .AsEnumerable()
               .Where( x => x.Number.ToString().Contains(search));
```

Comment: There is no SqlFunctions on uwp. .ToList() can be slow and occupy a lot of memory, but is a solution.

Comment: The solution. Thank you.

var query = cnn.Table<Employees>()
               .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search) || 
                           x.Number > 0)
      .AsEnumerable()
      .Where(x =>
               x.Number.ToString().Contains(search));

Comment: ya... Thought one can do that but didn't like it too much haha (but it is better that having both where conditions after the ToList()

Comment: Me too, but it is a matter of resource management. :) You forgot the condition x.Number > 0. Don't add it result in less results.