# How read a record with a specific date in C# with SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite

In a MAUI project I have a very simple table where I want to save the time an user spends on the app. For this reason, I define this model

```
public class Statistic
{
    public DateTime ScreenDate { get; set; }
    public long Minutes { get; set; }
}
```

then, in the persistence layer, I create the database and then I have a function where I try to read the record with a date. In the following code `dt` is a parameter defines as `DateTime`.

```
List<Statistic> rsl = await Database.Table<Statistic>()    
  .Where(s => 
         s.ScreenDate.ToShortDateString() == dt.ToShortDateString())
  .ToListAsync();
```

When I try to run this code, I get an error

> SQLite.SQLiteException: 'no such function: toshortdatestring'

I tried other functions - like ToString() - with the some result.

### Update

I tried to use `System.Data.Entity.SqlServer` like

```
List<Statistic> rsl = await Database.Table<Statistic>()
   .Where(s => SqlFunctions.DatePart("year", s.ScreenDate) == dt.Year &&
          SqlFunctions.DatePart("month", s.ScreenDate) == dt.Month &&
          SqlFunctions.DatePart("day", s.ScreenDate) == dt.Day).ToListAsync();
```

and I get the some error

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLite.Net-PCL No such function: ToString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761958/sqlite-net-pcl-no-such-function-tostring)

Comment: In this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761958/sqlite-net-pcl-no-such-function-tostring they talk specifically about string and contains. In my case I tried to use  `SqlFunctions.DatePart("year", s.ScreenDate)` but again I get the some error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQLite cannot convert your C# method to a SQL method. If you have tried to use *SqlFunctions* and it didn't work as well, let's use some classic and raw C# code and logic :)

```
var startDate = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day);
var endDate = startDate.AddDays(1);

var rsl = await Database.Table<Statistic>()
                        .Where(s => s.ScreenDate >= startDate && s.ScreenDate < endDate)
                        .ToListAsync();
```

What you want to get is the list of statistics for a specific day (ignoring time), so we just have to create new two variables, startDate, and endDate, where the startDate is your original date but ignoring time (00:00:00) and the endDate is the next day also ignoring time (00:00:00). After that we just have to filter greater or equals to startDate and less than endDate.

#### Real example:

**Original date:** 08/08/2023 10:07:25

**Start date variable:** 08/08/2023 00:00:00

**End date variable:** 09/08/2023 00:00:00

**Where condition:** ScreenDate >= 08/08/2023 00:00:00 **AND** ScreenDate < 09/08/2023 00:00:00

So it'll return all records that are between 08/08/2023 00:00:00 and 08/08/2023 23:59:59 (1 tick before the next day).